# Keep menu in UWP title bar draggable and resizable

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uno-platform

I'm trying to make a cross platform app with Uno, for desktop use specifically and I want to tailer the UWP build to put a menu in the title bar - which I can do.

What I cannot do is enable the window to remain resizable all the way around and draggable outside the menu in the titlebar.

I have tried a number of approaches and none of them seem to work I either get a working menu with no resize/drag or a resizable/draggable window with a non-functional menu.

This is what I have so far

at the bottom of App.xaml.cs->OnLaunched:

```
#if WINDOWS_UWP
      CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
      ApplicationView appView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
      appView.TitleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
      appView.TitleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
      appView.TitleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.DarkGray;
      appView.TitleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
      appView.TitleBar.InactiveBackgroundColor = Colors.Transparent;
#endif
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public MainPage()
{
  this.InitializeComponent();
  Window.Current.SetTitleBar(bkgTitleBar);
}
```

And the content of MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="ctlTitleBar" Background="Transparent">
            <Rectangle x:Name="bkgTitleBar" />
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Transparent">
                    <!--<Rectangle x:Name="bkgTitleBar" />-->
                    <MenuBar>
                        <MenuBarItem Title="File">
                            <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="New">
                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Plain Text Document"/>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Rich Text Document"/>
                                <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Other Formats..."/>
                            </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Open..."/>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Save"/>
                            <MenuFlyoutSeparator />
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Exit"/>
                        </MenuBarItem>

                        <MenuBarItem Title="Edit">
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Undo"/>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Cut"/>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Copy"/>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Paste"/>
                        </MenuBarItem>

                        <MenuBarItem Title="View">
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Output"/>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Raw"/>
                            <MenuFlyoutSeparator/>
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="External..."/>
                        </MenuBarItem>

                        <MenuBarItem Title="Help">
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="About"/>
                        </MenuBarItem>
                    </MenuBar>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Viewbox>
                <Grid MinWidth="1680">
                    <TextBlock Text="Oobey! Doobey! Doobey! Dooo!" Margin="20" FontSize="30" FontFamily="{StaticResource TextBlockFontFamily1}" />
                    <ToggleButton Content="clicky" FontWeight="Bold"  Margin="86,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="59" Width="233" FontSize="22" />
                    <ToggleButton Content="clicky2" FontWeight="Bold"  Margin="1519,276,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="59" Width="233" FontSize="22"/>
                </Grid>
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Ideally I want to be able to alter it in a way that will work like the Windows Photos app does when the "OneDrive" button shows up at the top.

Can anybody help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the element you set as "title bar" has non-zero dimensions and covers the area you would like to be draggable. In this case `bkgTitleBar` has no size and background by default, so instead try giving it a size:

```
<Rectangle 
   x:Name="bkgTitleBar" 
   Fill="Transparent" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

This should stretch the `Rectangle` to match the size of `ctlTitleBar`.

Comment: thats just the ticket!

Comment: while my edit is awaiting approval I should make clear that
Background="Transparent" should be changed to Fill="#00000000" .. appears the Rectangle has no Background property
For anyone else running into the same issue

Comment: @S.W. You are right, thanks, approved :-)